# javax Validator recursive validation by default

Tags: java, json, validation, javax

I have two classes where one is nested in the other. I'd like to deserialize and validate incoming JSON against this structure of mine. I have a javax Validator obtained by

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
```

And later I do:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> validate = validator.validate(obj);
```

Where `obj` is my deserialized JSON. My nested classes are

```
class Foo {

  @Min(5)
  Integer a;

  List<Bar> bars;

  static class Bar {
    @Min(2)
    Integer b;
  }
}
```

I know that, unless I specify `@Valid` annotation on my `List<Bar> bars` field, the `validator` is not going to make a recursive validation. However, I'd like the default behavior of the `validator` to be recursive.

Is there a way to do that when getting the instance of the `Validator`?

Comment: anyone knows how to achieve that ?

Comment: this is still a mystery :(

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [@Valid](https://javadoc.io/static/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/index.html?javax/validation/Valid.html), which allows for "validation cascading" (see [this example](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/bean-validation/cascaded-validation.html))

```
class Foo {

  @Min(5)
  Integer a;

  @Valid
  List<Bar> bars;

  static class Bar {
    @Min(2)
    Integer b;
  }
}
```